# Can we make chat notifications work on Firefox?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, firefox, desktop-notifications

With the release of [Firefox 22](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/22.0/releasenotes/) has come an implementation of the [Web Notifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) (draft) API. SE Chat has had notifications for a while, but a quick search of the minified code and the lack of a notifications option indicates that it uses `window.webkitNotifications`, which is of course specific to the WebKit engine.

Now, the W3C draft API is currently working on the current release versions of both Firefox and Chrome (test [here](http://jsbin.com/notification/522/edit)) ([some other browsers](http://caniuse.com/notifications) still only support the prefixed version for now). Would it be possible to have notification support for Firefox on SE Chat?

---

<sup>Previously, there was [an addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/html-notifications/) that implemented `window.webkitNotifications` for Firefox. Since native support was introduced, that addon has been discontinued, and no longer works on the latest version.</sup>

Comment: Based on balpha's response [to when I brought this up before](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1323882#1323882), the answer is yes. As for when, 6-8 weeks.

Comment: As a quick fix, you could install this userscript: `window.webkitNotifications = notifications`

Comment: @JanDvorak It looks like the two APIs are sufficiently different that a direct port would not work. Might not be too difficult to write a shim.

Comment: @TimStone So, uh. Any word? (approaching a year now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chat now uses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239114/115866) the current standard for desktop notifications, and this means it works in Firefox as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a shim/library/userscript which implements `webkitNotifications` for browsers which support `Notification`.

- Installation: from http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/172570.
- Source code: https://gist.github.com/Rob--W/5926727 (please submit patches if you find any errors)

Comment: I seem to have missed the notification of this answer! I went and [implemented my own](https://github.com/Elusive138/FF-webkitNotifications), though it has far more reliance on `Notification`, while yours does more of the work. I'm also very much a beginner with JavaScript, and the events aren't properly done. Apart from that, it *does* work for other people (but not myself on SE Chat, which is odd - it works on other sites for me). Anyway, thanks!