# Native desktop notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, notifications

Although it’s still a working draft, [Web Notifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) have been somewhat stable for quite a while now. In fact, they are stable enough that they [exist *unprefixed*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications) in current versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari. As for the first two, they have been for quite a while already.

Yet, in chat, the option *“enable desktop notifications”* only appears in WebKit browsers because the code checks explicitely for the prefixed `window.webkitNotifications`, making it not work in other browsers that support them.

I would suggest you to do something like this somewhere:

```
if (!window.Notification) {
    window.Notification = window.webkitNotification || window.mozNotification || window.oNotification || window.msNotification;
}
```

And then just use the standardized, unprefixed `window.Notification`.

Comment: Related, but I guess not a full duplicate: [Can we make chat notifications work on Firefox?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186500/can-we-make-chat-notifications-work-on-firefox)

Comment: @Arjan Interesting! I didn’t find that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code suggestion wouldn't have worked as easily, because those implementations weren't compatible; you couldn't just replace them with each other. Your point stands however, and is now completed: We're now using the standard (if only working draft) version that's supported in Chrome, FF, Safari 6, and Opera 25 (the next version).