# Desktop notifications broken in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, desktop-notifications

Chrome has now removed the prefixed `navigator.webkitNotifications` API and as a result desktop notifications no longer work. I'm not sure exactly when this happened, but it certainly doesn't work in the latest Chrome stable ( experimental evidence indicates this change was made between v34 and 35).

The unprefixed [`window.Notification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) API is now active in Chrome >=22, and converting to this would also allow it to work in Firefox >=22 and Safari 6 on OSX >=10.8.

Related: [Native desktop notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219607/native-desktop-notifications)

I genuinely do rate this a noticeable reduction in the general usefulness of chat, I use desktop notifications when I am at work and I would very much like them back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desktop notifications are back now. They'll only work in Chrome >= 32 [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Chrome_notes) (support was incomplete before that), but current stable is 37, so that shouldn't be an issue. It also works in Firefox.

Those are the two browsers I've tested; it's presumably also going to work in the next Opera version (25), and, as you said, it should also work in Safari 6+.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much!